# tkinter: Is it possible to attach GUIs from different tkinter programs together and easily navigate across them?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'd like to build a number of tkinter GUI apps and then stack them together either horizontally or vertically. I'd also like to navigate across the app easily once they become attached so that at any time I can focus on them.

One idea in my mind is that I can have a webpage like frame container, with a scrollbar, then drag other app's GUIs into it so that I can scroll across them.

To attach the windows, I understand that maybe I can get individual app's window through process info, but I just want to make sure if there is a built-in or better way of doing the things I want.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? When you are "stacking" the GUIs, do you expect each GUI to be a standalone program running in a separate process? Or, are you saying you want to create multiple programs, but also be able to combine those programs into a single program that shows the programs "stacked" horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you didn't capitalize tkinter, I'm going to assume that you are working in Python 3. If this is so, there are two options that I can think of: Using tkinter frames/grid geometry manager to place each widget side by side, and using tkinter.ttk Notebook to have multiple application tabs. you could also mess around with creating a scrollable tkinter Frame if you were dead set on the scrolling part, but from other Stackoverflow pages it appears that there is no native way to do that.

[Example of tkinter.ttk Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514617/python-tkinter-notebook-widget)