# Python Tkinter Notebook widget

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

Using [this python recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/541092-tknotebook/), i have created a notebook like widget on my Tk window. It all works fine until i tried to add an image into each tab. When i add image into the tab, the text i initially set were no longer shown. I am wondering if i can make the text (in this case is "tab one") to show right below the image.The following is my current code:

```
from Tkinter import *
class Notebook(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, activerelief = SOLID, inactiverelief = SOLID, xpad = 4, ypad = 4, activefg = 'black',activebg='green',inactivebg='grey',bd=1,inactivefg = 'black', **kw):                                                                
        self.activefg = activefg
        self.activebg=activebg
        self.bd=bd
        self.inactivebg=inactivebg
        self.inactivefg = inactivefg
        self.deletedTabs = []        
        self.xpad = xpad
        self.ypad = ypad
        self.activerelief = activerelief
        self.inactiverelief = inactiverelief                                               
        self.kwargs = kw                                                                   
        self.tabVars = {}                                                                 
        self.tabs = 0                                                                                                                                                 
        self.noteBookFrame = Frame(parent)                                                 
        self.BFrame = Frame(self.noteBookFrame)                                            
        self.noteBook = Frame(self.noteBookFrame, relief = RAISED, bd = 1, **kw)           
        self.noteBook.grid_propagate(0)                                                    
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.noteBookFrame.grid()
        self.BFrame.grid(row =0, sticky = W)
        self.noteBook.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 27)

    def add_tab(self, width = 1, **kw):            
            temp = self.tabs                                                                   
            self.tabVars[self.tabs] = [Label(self.BFrame, relief = RIDGE, **kw)]               
            self.tabVars[self.tabs][0].bind("<Button-1>", lambda Event:self.change_tab(temp))  
            self.tabVars[self.tabs][0].pack(side = LEFT, ipady = self.ypad, ipadx = self.xpad) 
            self.tabVars[self.tabs].append(Frame(self.noteBook, **self.kwargs))                
            self.tabVars[self.tabs][1].grid(row = 0, column = 0)                               
            self.change_tab(0)                                                                 
            self.tabs += 1                                                                     
            return self.tabVars[temp][1]
    def change_tab(self, IDNum): 
        for i in (a for a in range(0, len(self.tabVars.keys()))):
            if not i in self.deletedTabs:                                                  
                if i <> IDNum:                                                             
                    self.tabVars[i][1].grid_remove()                                       
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['relief'] = self.inactiverelief                     
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['fg'] = self.inactivefg
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['bg'] = self.inactivebg
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['bd'] = self.bd
                else:                                                                      
                    self.tabVars[i][1].grid()                                                                    
                    self.tabVars[IDNum][0]['relief'] = self.activerelief                   
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['fg'] = self.activefg
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['bg'] = self.activebg
                    self.tabVars[i][0]['bd'] = self.bd


root=Tk()
scheduledimage=PhotoImage(data="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")
note=Notebook(root, width= 400, height =400, activefg = 'red', inactivefg = 'blue')
note.grid()
tab1 = note.add_tab(text = "Tab One",image=scheduledimage)
tab2 = note.add_tab(text = "Tab Two")                                                
tab3 = note.add_tab(text = "Tab Three")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Label reference: [`compound`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method)

> Controls how to combine text and image in the label. By default, if an image or bitmap is given, it is drawn instead of the text. If this option is set to **CENTER**, the text is drawn on top of the image. If this option is set to one of **BOTTOM**, **LEFT**, **RIGHT**, or **TOP**, the image is drawn besides the text (use **BOTTOM** to draw the image under the text, etc.). Default is **NONE**.

```
tab1 = note.add_tab(text = "Tab One",image=scheduledimage, compound=TOP)
```

[`ttk.Notebook`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-notebook) sample:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

root = Tk()
scheduledimage=PhotoImage(...)
note = Notebook(root)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)
Button(tab1, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).pack(padx=100, pady=100)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tab One",image=scheduledimage, compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Tab Two")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.pack()
root.mainloop()
exit()
```

Comment: Is there an answer for this that doesn't use `ttk`? The context I'm working in does not have `ttk` (I do have `bwidget`, though).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of above code :

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

root = Tk()
scheduledimage=PhotoImage(...)
note = Notebook(root)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)
Button(tab1, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).pack(padx=100, pady=100)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tab One",image=scheduledimage, compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Tab Two")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.pack()
root.mainloop()
exit()
```

**try this one, it will work :-)**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
scheduledimage=PhotoImage("...")
note = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(note)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(note)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(note)

Button(tab1, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).pack(padx=100, pady=100)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tab One",image=scheduledimage, compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Tab Two")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.pack()

root.mainloop()
```